# Batch, copy and rename latest file from all subdirectories

Tags: batch-file, copy-paste, batch-rename, subdirectory

I'm stuck on this script I'm trying to write where I can accomplish individual parts of it, I cannot seem to put it together.

Within a folder, there are many sub folders with .mp4 files in it where a new file is generated every so often in any of the sub-directories. The script should be able to loop through each folder, and determine which file from all of them is the latest one and copy it to a specified folder, while renaming it to "Current.mp4"

What I have so far is a mess:
This will copy the file in a sub directory, but not loop through the rest

```
REM Copy the most recent database backups from their folders 
@echo off

REM Copy File in one destination to another --------------------------------------------

setlocal
set srcDir=P:\
set destdir=D:\
set lastmod=



pushd %srcDir%
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /S *.mp4 /D /b /o-d /a-d /t:c') do set lastmod=%%a
:::
copy "%lastmod%" "%destDir%"
```

Meanwhile this one seems to loop, but only refers to the latest file within the .bat directory.

```
setlocal
set destdir=D:\
SET srcDir=P:\

pushd %srcDir%

FOR /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /ad /s') do (
     pushd "%%~I"
     pushd %srcDir%
     FOR /F "delims=*" %%G IN ('DIR *=.mp4 /B /A:-D /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%G
     popd
)
popd

:::
copy "%NewestFile%" "%destdir%"
```

And finally renaming I figured I could figure out how to do last. I've had experience with c++ but batch is relatively new to me. Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Batch isn't good at sorting over folder boundaries for general attributes.

I'd use PowerShell for this, wrapped in a batch (untested) :

```
:: Q:\Test\2018\11\09\SO_53230483.cmd
@echo off & setlocal
set "srcDir=P:\"
set "destdir=D:\"
set "lastmod="

For /f "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`
  powershell -NoP -C "(Get-ChildItem -Path '%srcDir%' -Filter '*.mp4' -File -Recurse | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).FullName"
`) Do Set "lastmod=%%a"

If defined lastmod (
   copy "%lastmod%" "%destDir%Current.mp4"
) else (
   Echo couldn't obtain lastmod file
)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You're amazing, I've been trying for so long! I think I'll get more accustomed to powershell functions from now on.

Answer (score 1):

WMIC could be used, if you prefer not to use PowerShell:

```bat
@For /F "EOL=L Tokens=1*" %%A In ('
    "WMIC DataFile Where (Drive='P:' And Extension='mp4') Get LastModified,Name 2>Nul|Sort /R"
') Do @Call:CopyIt %%B&GoTo :X
:X
@Exit/B
:CopyIt
@If Not "%*"=="" Copy /Y "%*" "D:\current.mp4"&Exit/B
```

*The above is only an example, and would need modification, if your source wasn't the root of a drive or you had file names which included ampersands.*

Answer (score 0):

Not quite there yet but I've found how to scan ONE directory and copy the latest file while renaming it. I just need to have it scan all sub directories instead.

```
pushd P:\
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir /b /od') do set newest=%%a
copy "%newest%" "D:\Current.mp4
popd
```